# Error in running hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hue

When I run following commmand in hive

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/beeline -u jdbc:hive2://
```

Following error is shown attached in the link
[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_5cLrHOPHNLWE4zOW5kMXlSUVU/view?usp=sharing).

please help!

Comment: try this :lauch beeline first $HIVE_HOME/bin/beeline  , then  beeline >  !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 scott tiger org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

Comment: Shows error `Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (state=08S01,code=0)
`

Comment: is your hiveserver2 running ! check : ps -aux | grep hive-server2

Answer (score 0):

You can also try one liner as per below.

```
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://ip-hive-server-ip separated with hifen>:10000/default;principal=driver-details" -n $USER
```

Answer (score 0):

1. At First check if your hive server is listening on port 10000?

   **netstat -an | grep 10000**

   if not! go to **/tmp/{username}/hive.log** and see what is wrong!
2. If hive server is up and running, then check the schema that you were created!

   **schematool -validate -dbType  -verbose**

   if the schema has problems, then you should init the schema again.
3. If everything is OK, then you should connect using:

   **beeline -u jdbc:hive2://{IP or servername}:10000**